# Find a subspace $W$ such that ... - am I right?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ spanned by $v_1=(1,-1,1,2)$ and $v_2=(3,1,2,1)$. Find a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb R^4$ such that $U ∩ W = \{{0}\}$ and $\dim(U) + \dim(W) = \dim(\mathbb{R^4})$.

Now obviously, $v_1,v_2$ form a basis for $U$ and thus $\dim(U)=2$. Now if I get it right, all I need to do, is to find two vectors $v_3,v_4$ such that all $4$ of them would be linearly independent thus forming a basis for $\mathbb R^4$ and complying with constraints. And so for example $v_3=(1,0,0,0)$ and $v_4=(0,1,0,0)$ does the job, as then $\dim(W)=2$ and $\dim(U)+ \dim(W)=4$. right?

Comment: Do you know about the orthogonal complement?

Comment: no, or at least, not yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've done is correct.  You should provide some justification that the vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, and $v_4$ are indeed independent (and maybe even why this suffices to solve the problem). Also, the problem asked for the *subspace* $W$; so, your answer should be phrased as "$W$ is the subspace spanned by $v_3$ and $v_4$".

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand and am able to provide the justifications, just wanted to make sure that I am not mistaken. Thank you again!

Comment: @Sarunas You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you found the two vectors by trying a couple of them. However, in general it's not so easy to find them by shooting in the dark. If the space was $\mathbb{R}^{200}$ and $U$ had a basis consisting of $42$ vectors, trying the various possibilities would be very inefficient.

You have a couple of strategies available.

### Strategy 1

If you know about Gaussian elimination, you can build the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4\end{bmatrix}
$$
and do the row reduction. The column space of this matrix is obviously the whole of $\mathbb{R}^4$, so the dominant columns will correspond to a basis and the theory about Gaussian Elimination guarantees that $v_1$ and $v_2$ will be among them.
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4\end{bmatrix}
&=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\to\\
&\to\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -5 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\to\\
&\to\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -3/4 & 1/4 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -3/4 & 5/4 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\to\\
&\to\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1/3 & -4/3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
From this reduced form you deduce that
$$
\{v_1,v_2,e_1,e_2\}
$$
is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and so a solution for your problem is
$$
W=\operatorname{Span}\{e_1,e_2\}.
$$

### Strategy 2

The orthogonal complement of $U$ is the null space of the matrix $A^T$, where $A=\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2\end{bmatrix}$.

Thus you need to find the null space of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that can be done again with Gaussian elimination.
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 4 & -1 & -5
\end{bmatrix}\to\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -1/4 & -5/4
\end{bmatrix}\to\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3/4 & 3/4 \\
0 & 1 & -1/4 & -5/4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
This is equivalent to the system
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=-3x_3/4 - 3x_4/4\\
x_2=x_3/4 + 5x_4/4
\end{cases}
$$
and you get two linearly independent vectors by choosing first $x_3=4$ and $x_4=0$, then $x_3=0$ and $x_4=4$. The two vectors are
$$
w_1=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\1\\4\\0\end{bmatrix},\qquad
w_2=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\5\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: WOW, thank you for the insights! these are very useful!